# I have searched through stack exchange and haven't found any successful ways to make my printbibliography work, any suggestions?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, apa-style

I have searched and spent hours researching how to get my bibliography to work. 
This is the beginning of my document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[citestyle=alphabetic,bibstyle=apa,backend=biber,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,threshold=2]{csquotes}



\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}

\title{Lab technologist/science professional}
\author{Jesslynn Westfall SN, SCC}

\addbibresource{labtechbib.bib}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \section{Introduction}
    Sometimes called medical laboratory science (MLS) professionals, lab technologists perform many tasks that help improve health care. Though they are sometimes called lab technicians, more schooling is required to become a technologist/scientist.\cite{MLT}
```

and this is the end

```
    \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={References}]


\end{document}
```

Here is an example of my bibliography:

```
@misc{medtechschool,
    mendeley-groups = {Nursing},
    title = {{Medical Lab Scientist MLS (ASCP) Certification}},
    url = {https://www.medicaltechnologyschools.com/medical-lab-scientist/mls-ascp-certification},
    urldate = {2020-04-06}
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Did you compile it with PDFLaTeX then BibTeX then PDFLaTeX again?

Comment: You have to run biber and not bibtex. See https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber

Comment: @Johannes_B I tried to change it and got this message "File `biber.sty' not found. \usepackage"

Comment: Please follow the link i gave you and read the content of that page. It will take you between 15 and 30 minutes, though.

Comment: See also [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751)

Comment: Also, it's not really a good idea to use a different cite style with the `apa` biblatex style. It's specifically designed to implement the APA requirements. If you want a basic author year style (commonly called 'APA style') use `bibstyle=authoryear` not `apa`.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thank you! I went through it and realized some stuff I needed to change in the program but I got this message: " ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.7, expected version 3.4.
This means that your biber (2.11) and biblatex (3.14) versions are incompatible.
See compat matrix in biblatex or biber PDF documentation.
INFO - ERRORS: 1 " and I'm not sure how to fix this

Comment: There is a version mismatch. An update of biblatex and biber using the package manager would help.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! I had to update my packages which I didn't know I had to so thank you very much. I also took into consideration all of the coding tips so thank you for those!